# How to code operation overload so it operates to a specific class member such as A<<{{1,2,3},{5,6,7}} in c++?

Tags: c++

You can redefine operator << in class by overload it.
However, how do you code it so that it would operates specific to a certain class member?
for example

```
class C
{
   int a;
   double b;
}
// I would like something like 
void main ()
{
   C c;
   c.a << 1; // sets class member a to value 1;
}
```

I want a operator defined in Class C that operates specifically to class member a.

a pesudo-code would be

```
class C
{
  int a;
  double b;
  void operator << (istream & fin)
  {
    ... fin.get()... some code 
  }
}
```

Comment: Make `int a;` `public` and `c.a = 1`?

Comment: Why can't you just use equals? If you're giving a user the ability to use a class member's name, then it's not private. If you're giving the user the ability to set its value to anything they want, then it's not private.

Comment: Once you write `c.a`, you've left the class. Are you thinking of something along the lines of `c << 1` sets `c.a` while `c << 1.0` would set `c.b`?

Comment: @justANewbie   I want to do operation on it other than setting a value.

Comment: @jojo_Aero_smith_the_dummy You can do any operation in `c.a` like you do with an `int`

Comment: @JaMiT yes, lefting the class is the problem. That is why I want to overload the operator within the class. But in addition, I want the operation to operate specifically to that class member. The only way I could think of doing this is struct within class.

Answer (score 2):

Stating the obvious for a moment, assuming the variable is public, you'd use:

```cpp
class C
{
   int a;
   double b;
}
// I would like something like 
void main ()
{
   C c;
   c.a = 1; // sets class member a to value 1;
}
```

The `<<` and `>>` operators are bit shifts, which have their own meaning. Overloading those for your own purpose is probably a bad idea.

The C++ way of doing things is to avoid setting member variables externally where possible *(e.g. using RAII approaches, to set data at initialisation)*....

```cpp
class C
{
public:
   C(int a, double b) : a(a), b(b) {}
   int getA() const { return a; }
   double getB() const { return b; }
private:
   int a;
   double b;
};
```

.... Or by adding a setter method if you really need it, e.g.

```cpp
class C
{
public:
   C(int a, double b) : a(a), b(b) {}
   int getA() const { return a; }
   double getB() const { return b; }
   void setA(int v) { a = v; }
   void setB(double v) { b = v; }
private:
   int a;
   double b;
};
```

You could in theory generate a new type, and overload the operators for that type, but it's not something I'd recommend *(because changing the meaning of an operator is almost always a bad idea)*

```cpp
struct MyIntType {
  int i;
  // overload cast operator
  operator int () {
    return i;
  }
  // assign
  MyIntType& operator = (const int& v) {
     i = v;
     return *this;
  }
  // not recommended :(
  MyIntType& operator << (const int& v) {
     i = v;
     return *this;
  }
};
class C
{
public:
   MyIntType a;
   double b;
};
void main ()
{
   C c;
   c.a << 1; 
}
```

Having read your comment above, it sounds like you want to do this:

```cpp
class C
{
public:

  // I'm still not recommending this :(
  C& operator << (const int& v) {
     a = v;
     return *this;
  }

private:
   int a;
   double b;
};
void main ()
{
   C c;
   c << 1; //< now sets c.a 
}
```

Comment: I guess the only way to do this is by defining your own mini-class with overloaded operator and realize a object of the class within the large class.

Comment: Yes. You can't overload the << operator for existing types (because those types, and the operator in question, already have been defined, and have specific meanings - in this case bitshift). The fact that the iostream designers decided to overload the bitshift operators, doesn't really make it a good idea. Human readable functions (that explain what the code is doing) is almost always the best approach imho.